# Query failed with error code 2 and error message 'cannot set maxTimeMS on getMore command for a non-awaitData cursor' on server

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, vert.x

I am getting above error when I am aggregating on mongo collection with vertx mongo client, can anyone please help me whats the problem here

```
at com.mongodb.operation.QueryHelper.translateCommandException(QueryHelper.java:31)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:294)
    at com.mongodb.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:276)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:205)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:100)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:458)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:110)
    at com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:49)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:383)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:359)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:651)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:618)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:487)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:484)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:233)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:216)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:158)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.implRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:562)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:277)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.read(AsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:298)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.readAsync(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:128)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:484)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$1100(InternalStreamConnection.java:74)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:608)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:593)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:487)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:484)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:233)
    at com.mongodb.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$BasicCompletionHandler.completed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:216)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:127)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finishRead(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:439)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.finish(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:191)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.onEvent(UnixAsynchronousSocketChannelImpl.java:213)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.KQueuePort$EventHandlerTask.run(KQueuePort.java:312)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:112)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Here is my code:

```
JsonObject pricing_config = new JsonObject()
                .put("host", config().getString("pricing_host", ""))
                .put("port", Integer.parseInt(config().getString("pricing_port", "0")))
                .put("username", config().getString("pricing_username", ""))
                .put("password", config().getString("pricing_password", ""))
                .put("db_name", config().getString("pricing_db_name", ""))
                //.put("authSource", config().getString("pricing_authSource", ""))
                .put(MongoConstants.USE_OBJECT_ID_KEY, true);

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClient.createNonShared(this.vertx, pricing_config);
        AggregateOptions options = new AggregateOptions()
                //.setMaxTime(20000)
                //.setMaxAwaitTime(20000)
                .setBatchSize(20)
                .setAllowDiskUse(true);

        return this.mongoClient.aggregateWithOptions(aggregationCollection, pipeline, options)
                .toFlowable()
                .map(res -> res.getString("_id"))
                .toList();
```

I tried with various options with AggregateOptions but didnt work,
The problem here it is not able to fetch subsequent batches as the cursor got timed out after fetching the first batch, if I increase it to Integer.MAX it will work only for 16 mb of data in one batch otherwise it will again fail.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer for this, which is very simple
As error says, you cant set the `MaxTimeMs` parameter to aggregate options where your aggregation operation is returning non Await data cursor
RC here is default value for MaxTimeMs is 1000 MS, so by explicitly setting MaxTimeMs to zero, you can solve this problem.

So you aggregation options looks like below,

```
AggregateOptions options = new AggregateOptions()
                    .setBatchSize(10000)
                    .setMaxAwaitTime(0)
                    .setAllowDiskUse(true);
```